# The program 'curl' is currently not installed

Tags: 16.04

I have a problem about curl package:"**Package 'curl' has no installation candidate**"
how to solve it?

Comment: eh. normally there is a notice below it saying how to install it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change the server to main server

Open **System settings** > **Software & Updates** > **Ubuntu Software** > make sure you have all the source selected (*main*, *universe*, *restricted*, and *multiverse*) and select download from Main server.

Now try again `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install curl`

Answer (score 1):

Normaly, it is `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install curl` at 16.04.

It should work @xenial, if not, you have the wrong sources installed.